# Why is it failing to connect with oracle Autonomous Database from golang?

Tags: oracle, go, oracle-autonomous-db

```
    dsn := `
user=ADMIN,
password=temp1!a,
(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.ap-seoul-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=gee9edfb93f3cf6_redglqweyxqefhhf_high.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=adb.ap-seoul-1.oraclecloud.com, OU=Oracle ADB SEOUL, O=Oracle Corporation, L=Redwood City, ST=California, C=US")))
`

db, err := sql.Open("godror", dsn)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer db.Close()
```

I created an autonomous database, and I try to connect with the above code in golang, but it is impossible to connect with the following error, how to connect, I cannot find a detailed manual, can you help me?

```
go run main.go
parsing parameters "user=ADMIN,\n\tpassword=temp1!a,\n\t(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.ap-seoul-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=gee9edfb93f3cf6_redglqweyxqefhhf_high.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn=\"CN=adb.ap-seoul-1.oraclecloud.com, OU=Oracle ADB SEOUL, O=Oracle Corporation, L=Redwood City, ST=California, C=US\")))": logfmt syntax error at pos 44 on line 3: unexpected '='
```

Comment: The dsn format is not right.

Comment: Connection parameters should be placed into `connectString` key: see https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/godror/godror#readme-connection. Also please verify if commas can be parsed correctly as they are absent in the docs

Comment: db, error := sql.Open("godror", `user="scott" password="tiger" connectString="dbhost:1521/orclpdb1"

I checked this part, what part should be missing in connectString??

Comment: Doesn't Oracle's db information need to be entered? How do I connect to my db in oracle?

Comment: Cloud-based Oracle ADB requires the use of an Oracle wallet with certificates to support the TCPS protocol: you should be using the TNSNAMES alias for the connection, with all of the connect specifications provided by Oracle. Also, please tell me you didn't post the *actual* connection data, with username and password, in your original question...

Comment: Can you show me a simple example?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a new user of oracle and golang, everything is new, and I had difficulty finding documentation to connect oracle and golang. There is a manual, but I did not understand it well.

If you post a question on stackoverflow, the answers are only links to the manual. It was really hard for beginners to experience a new environment

I finally found a solution and my code is below. Even if you don't understand the code, it would be nice to think about it one by one while looking at the examples.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    go_ora "github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2"
)

type DbInfo struct {
    Username string
    Password string
}

func main() {
    serverInfo := DbInfo{
        Username: "databaseUser",
        Password: "databaseUserPassword",
    }
    urlOptions := map[string]string{
        "TRACE FILE": "trace.log",
        "SSL VERIFY": "FALSE",
    }
    connectString := "(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.ap-seoul-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=gvsd1dfc9c3cdf6_racc7y8cxsvb16f0z_medium.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=yes)))"

    db, err := sql.Open("oracle", go_ora.BuildJDBC(serverInfo.Username, serverInfo.Password, connectString, urlOptions))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    r, err := db.Exec(`create table users (
        nickname varchar(20)
    )`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(r.LastInsertId())
}
```

The code above does not require a wallet for tls access. I'll also upload how to access it through the wallet below, for beginners who need it.